# Вывод видео в галерею вместе с изображениями - php

Tags: php, wordpress, видео, img, gallery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, что бы в галерее изображений можно было выводить еще и видео?

Есть php-код, который отображает только изображения. Как его изменить и что надо добавить?

```
<?php 
$project_gallery = get_field( "slajder" );
?>

      <div class="row">
        <?php if( $project_gallery ): ?>
          <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-7 col-12">
            <div class="project-slider">
              <div class="project-slider__content" id="project-slider">
                <?php foreach( $project_gallery as $image ): ?>
                  <div class="project-slider__slide">
                    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" class="project-slider__image">
                    <video controls="" autoplay="" name="media" src="<?php echo $video['url']; ?>" type="video/mp4" class="project-slider__image"></video> //надо, что бы вот это выводилось вместе с изображениями
                  </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
              </div>
```

Comment: Откуда берется переменная `$video` в цикле?

Comment: Неоткуда. Эту строчку с выводом видео добавил я! И если в методе foreach я меняю переменную $image на $video, то в галереи выводится только видео. А надо что бы выводились и изображения и видео.

Comment: Извините, наверное я не правильно объясняю. Изначально код без этой строчки <video controls="" autoplay="" name="media" src="<?php echo $video['url']; ?>" type="video/mp4" class="project-slider__image"></video>. Если я в админке в галерею добавляю видео, то к нему подставляется тег <img>  и соответственно видео не отображается на сайте. Надо, что бы к видео подставлялся тег <video>. Надеюсь, что теперь понятно объяснил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну должно быть что-то вроде:

```
<?php $project_gallery = get_field('slajder'); ?>
<div class="row">
    <?php if ($project_gallery): ?>
        <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-7 col-12">
            <div class="project-slider">
                <div class="project-slider__content" id="project-slider">
                    <?php foreach($project_gallery as $item) : ?>
                        <div class="project-slider__slide">
                            <?php if ($item['type'] === 'image') : ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo esc_url($item['url']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($item['alt']); ?>" class="project-slider__image">
                            <?php elseif ($item['type'] === 'video') : ?>
                                <video controls="" autoplay="" name="media" src="<?php echo esc_url($item['url']); ?>" type="video/mp4" class="project-slider__image"></video>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Я заменил `$image` на `$item`, чтобы было более релевантно. Просто проверяйте `$item['type']` тип файла, в случае с картинкой будет `'image'`, в случае с видео, будет `'video'` соответственно.

Comment: Огромное СПАСИБО! Все работает! Код рабочий!